# What is __utmt and __utmd cookies in analytics

Tags: cookies, google-analytics

I am doing a web penetration test on our site and report fails die to 2 cookies from google analytics

1) __utmt
2) __utmd

Anyone know what these cookies are and if there are any documentation on them. (couldnt find them in google sites)

Thanks in advance

Comment: utmt = Indicates the type of request, which is one of: event, transaction, item, or custom variable. If this value is not present in the GIF request, the request is typed as page. (source: https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gaTrackingTroubleshooting). Don't know about utmd before though. Are you sure it's not utmdt, which is "Page title, which is a URL-encoded string"?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very old question, but in case someone is also searching for some information on this, like me ...

**__utmt** (expiration: 10 minutes)
*"Used to throttle request rate."*

**__utmd** I wasn't able to find ...

---

Here my general researches **... from 11th March 2020 ...**

Link from Google with all Cookie Information: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookie-usage#gajs

> ---
>
> **Cookie Name** --- `Default Expiration Time` --- Description
>
> **__utma** --- `2 years from set/update` --- Used to distinguish users and sessions. The cookie is created when the javascript library executes and no existing __utma cookies exists. The cookie is updated every time data is sent to Google Analytics.
>
> **__utmt** --- `10 minutes` --- Used to throttle request rate.
>
> **__utmb** --- `30 mins from set/update` --- Used to determine new sessions/visits. The cookie is created when the javascript library executes and no existing __utmb cookies exists. The cookie is updated every time data is sent to Google Analytics.
>
> **__utmc** --- `End of browser session` --- Not used in ga.js. Set for interoperability with urchin.js. Historically, this cookie operated in conjunction with the __utmb cookie to determine whether the user was in a new session/visit.
>
> **__utmz** --- `6 months from set/update` --- Stores the traffic source or campaign that explains how the user reached your site. The cookie is created when the javascript library executes and is updated every time data is sent to Google Analytics.
>
> **__utmv** --- `2 years from set/update` --- Used to store visitor-level custom variable data. This cookie is created when a developer uses the _setCustomVar method with a visitor level custom variable. This cookie was also used for the deprecated _setVar method. The cookie is updated every time data is sent to Google Analytics.
>
> ---

Answer (score 0):

**__utma**  Used to distinguish users and sessions. The cookie is created when the javascript library executes and no existing __utma cookies exists. The cookie is updated every time data is sent to Google Analytics.

you can find more details about all the cookies from here :

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookie-usage